# How to map controller method to URL with anchor?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I'm trying to create mapping for this url in my controller class:

```
@RequestMapping("/book/read/{bookId}#page-{pageNumber}")
```

On result page i want to see preloaded page (for example 5) and empty pages for all others, they will be loaded via ajax.

If i send request to http://mylocalhost.test:8080/book/read/538f10bfe4b0afcc723edb88#page-5 i see no handler method for such url message in log file

I think Spring ignore everything after # when trying to resolve handler method, but at the same time Spring allows me to make mapping with anchors in my controller method.
Spring looks this

```
/book/read/538f10bfe4b0afcc723edb88
```

but my method mapped to this

```
/book/read/538f10bfe4b0afcc723edb88#page-5
```

Of course  if i change mapping to

```
@RequestMapping("/book/read/{bookId}/page-{pageNumber}")
```

requests for this url starts work as expected. But i need this anchor positioning in my browser.

Is it possible to get this anchor feature in this way?

Comment: fragment identifiers (anchors) are client side - spring has no way of knowing them

Comment: Why not simply map to `/book/read/{bookId}/page-{pageNumber}` instead?

Comment: Bart i need browser anchor view after page render